# Capybara with selenium, send_key doesn't work

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, nokogiri

I'm using Cucumber to test a comment form that doesn't have a submit button. I found that selenium has a method called send_key, which in theory should allow me to do this:

```
find_field('my-field').native.send_key(:enter)
```

But when I run my test, I get:

```
undefined method `send_key' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x007f874b361828> (NoMethodError)
```

Not a clue what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have a typo: find_field('my-field').native.send_keys(:enter)

Comment: send_key is an alias for send_keys. Neither of them are recognized.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the Selenium driver and not the `:rack_test` driver in Capybara to access the `send_keys` method:

- Install the gem `selenium-webdriver` and add it to your gem file if you are using bundler.
- Mark your test using `:js => true` so that it runs with the Selenium driver.

You get an error because by default, Capybara uses the `:rack_test` driver. Calling `native` on an element access the driver specific methods. `:rack_test` driver elements are implemented natively as `Nokogiri::XML::Element`, therefore the `send_keys` methods do not exists and you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with xpath

```
within(:xpath, "//form[@id='the_form']") do
  locate(:xpath, "//input[@name='the_input']").set(value)
  locate(:xpath, "//input[@name='the_input']").node.send_keys(:return)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a hidden button. Capybara can see it and click it.

```
<%= form.submit "OK", style: "display: none;" %>
```

Then in your test:

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
click_on "OK"
```